# How to present dictionary and its dictionary entries using schema.org?

Tags: seo, schema.org

The website contains a bilingual dictionary with several thousand dictionary entries. Each entry is generated into own web page that is indexed by Search engines. (in other words, there are several thousand web pages)

```
Entry - the Name of the Dictionary
Url of the entry page
Information
```

The entry and the name of the Dictionary is correct (it is loaded from the name of the page). I would like to improve the Information section of the search result (now it shows the conjugation information that can be found later in the page).

Can I display the correct information by adding `schema.org` `microdata`? Are the items correctly nested inside the Book?

```
<div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Book">
  <div itemprop="name"> the Name of the Dictionary </div>
  <div id="Entry" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Thing">
    <div itemprop="name"> Entry </div>
    <div itemprop="description">
 the whole Entry
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update**
I use meta description in the head of the document. Information there is general about the dictionary. It seems that this information is replaced by more relevant information directly from the web page.

```
<meta name="description" content="the Description of the Dictionary">
```

Comment: *...web page contains a dictionary with several thousand dictionary entries...* Do you mean that there is one huge page with all of the dictionary terms? This is a bad idea. Very bad. I would recommend not doing this at all. If this is not what you mean, then it may help to clarify this so that we understand. Cheers!!

Comment: I have updated the question. Each entry has its own web page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After browsing the [schema.org docs](http://schema.org/docs/full.html) I could not find a suitable data type. If you can do without schema markup I would suggest using the [definition list HTML element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl) to markup your content. This will convey the context of the information on the page to search engines as a term with a definition. For example(from [2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl)):

```
<dl>
  <dt>Firefox</dt>
  <dd>A free, open source, cross-platform,
      graphical web browser developed by the
      Mozilla Corporation and hundreds of
      volunteers.</dd>

  <!-- other terms and descriptions -->
</dl>
```

If you are set on using the [Book item](http://schema.org/Book), which I don't believe to be valid, you may find using JSON-LD Schema formatting to be more efficient than inline schema format. An overview of the JSON-LD format can be found on the [Google Schemas site](https://developers.google.com/schemas/formats/json-ld). It is much more flexible since it is not directly tied to the HTML.

Comment: Ok, I have followed your advice and have placed <dl></dl> definion tags (hide them actually for users). Together with structured data Book and Item validated, it will be fine. Thank you for advice.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend hiding the elements. Google isn't a fan of indexing non-visible content and it may raise some spam flags.

Comment: Interesting information, thank you. Google has to remember that it indexes the information not only for the humans :).